# Can docker manage the host's hosts file?

Tags: docker

I use Docker under Windows and develop a small web app for *example.com*.

In my dev environment, I use the ip address to connect to my container group (localhost:8000), which works just fine.

But before I finally deploy to production, I want to confirm the prod-images are also working fine. But the prod image only listens on example.com:80. Can I tell docker to add `127.0.0.1 example.com` to my hosts file (`c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`) while the container is running?.

Comment: dont deal domain-wise routing on docker envs. use port wise routing instead

Comment: In general, a container can't modify the host's network environment; this is doubly true on non-Linux hosts and using Docker Desktop.